# Which cross-platform mobile application support well for Blackberry?

Tags: mobile, titanium, cross-platform, ibm-mobilefirst

I used Titanium for my project. It really supports well for Android and IOS. Our app runs really smooth with native feel on these two platforms. We need run it on Blackberry too. But Titanium doesn't support Blackberry well.

Do anybody know any cross-platform mobile application that support well for Android,IOS,Blackberry also?

I heard about the IBM Worklight. Does it support well for BlackBerry? Does it support well for IOS and Android also?

Thanks,
Chinh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be noted: "questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow". Your question will get closed soon.

*My biased opinion* is that Worklight can provide a very high level of development support, features and functionality for both Android and iOS, from both a web and native perspective. BlackBerry support is lower than that for Android and iOS, but by using a combination of the Worklight framework and optionally the bbUI framework & API, you will likely be able to create a decent BlackBerry app as well. However, it would be better to target BB10 than BB6/7.

You can take a look at the Worklight-based Bank of Montreal app for BlackBerry 10 for impressions: http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/46442891/?lang=en&countrycode=CA